# Wordpress plugin subscribe2 not looking the same as before migration

Tags: plugins, widgets, subscription

I migrated my wordpress, and the subscribe2 plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/subscribe2/installation/

looks different now. Before it has a text box with a placeholder, and then two buttons under saying subscribe and unsubscribe. The old plugin was version 4.16, and now the new version is 10.21. The way the new version looks like, is there is no input field or buttons. Rather it's just a sentence that says "you may manage your subscription options from your profile". And "profile" is a link.

Does anyone know how to get it to look like the old way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [developers tab](https://wordpress.org/plugins/subscribe2/developers/) you can find there all the previous versions:

> [4.16](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/subscribe2.4.16.zip)

you will have to install the plugin manually uploading the ZIP, this is not the correct way! always try to work with the latest version, but you can use the old version in the meantime, consider hiring a developer to make it look like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, if I was logged in, then it shows up as a sentence, but if you're not logged in, then it shows up with the input field and buttons.